# Multistream Wikipedia dump

Tags: xml, wiki, wikipedia, bzip2, wikimedia-dumps

I downloaded the german wikipedia dump dewiki-20151102-pages-articles-multistream.xml. My short question is: What does the 'multistream' mean in this case?

Answer (score 26):

The dumps are compressed using bz2, bz2 support a parallel version allowing it to compress/decompress files faster .
Compressed data using the parallel version is tagged as `multistream`.

Knowing this information makes a difference when you are processing the dump from a programming language, since you have to pass a flag to tell the library how to uncompress it (parallel or non parallel).

Comment: Could you please answer this question: 
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48386791/extract-related-articles-in-different-languages-using-wikidata-toolkit?noredirect=1#comment84061677_48386791

Answer (score 5):

`multistream` allows the use of an index to decompress sections as needed without having to decompress the entire thing.

This allows a reader to pull articles out of a compressed dump.